# php grabbing every post made?

Tags: php

Uh oh! So I added a page-blog.php with the following code:

```
<article>

    <?php // Display blog posts on any page @ http://m0n.co/l
    $temp = $wp_query; $wp_query= null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query(); $wp_query->query('showposts=5' . '&paged='.$paged);
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Read more"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php if ($paged > 1) { ?>

    <nav id="nav-posts">
        <div class="prev"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Previous Posts'); ?></div>
        <div class="next"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Posts &raquo;'); ?></div>
    </nav>

    <?php } else { ?>

    <nav id="nav-posts">
        <div class="prev"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Previous Posts'); ?></div>
    </nav>

    <?php } ?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

</article>
```

Then I go to my pages or categories and select that template to be used. The issue, is that when I go to a page or category with this template selected, it seems to be grabbing EVERY post I've ever made, not the posts I've assigned to particular categories.

So, my wordpress is set up with static pages (like my home page, contact page etc) that never get posts. They stay the same. Then, I have categories (acting like pages) which get all my posts. I assign each post to a category I want them to show up on. So, if I add a new recipe, I'll make a new post, assign it to the category "Recipes" and then it should show up on that page.

However, now, with this code and template, I'm getting EVERY post showing up on ALL of my category pages.

What do I need to change? Is there an easier way to make this work?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Based on WordPress template hierarchy, categories are displayed using the `category.php` template. So in other to display your preferred category, you'll need to create a `category.php` file, and use the query below:

```
$cat_query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type'         =>  'post',
        'cat'               =>  $cat, //WordPress global for getting the current category
        'posts_per_page'    =>  5,
        )
    );
```

And then you loop like so:

```
if( $cat_query->have_posts() ) : while( $cat_query->have_posts() ): $cat_query->the_post();
```

Comment: Oh that makes more sense. Ok, so I'll create a category.php with that query. ... Where do I put the loops? Does that go in index.php? In any particular play? ... And then how does the loops differentiate between static pages and categories? Does that query only become effective if there happens to be a category with posts?

Comment: The loop will be in your `category.php` file. WordPress does the work of calling the file whenever a category is queried. You can use WordPress default theme as an example.

Comment: Why the downvote!??

Comment: I didn't downvote, but there is no need for a `wp_query` in a category template, or basically any template

Comment: I didn't down vote either. However, I found an easier solution online. <?php 
   wp_nav_menu( array(
 'theme_location' => 'primary',
 'menu_class'     => 'primary-menu',
 ) );
?> This grabs all pages correctly, including categories with respective posts. Thanks for your help

Comment: 1+ for getting an easier solution.